# Unable to open feature class Failed to execute (RasterToPolygon)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcpy, error, raster-conversion

I'm trying yo execute the RastertoPolygon conversion tool in ArcGIs 10.1. I'm executing it through a for loop, then it resulted to an error (Unable to open feature class Failed to execute (RasterToPolygon)) at the python console. As I checked for some output, the first raster from the list is successfully converted to shp file while the rest are not. Any suggestions? 
Note: (All of my rasters are already in integer data type)

```
    #import the module
    import arcpy
    from arcpy.sa import *
    from arcpy import env
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
    env.overwriteOutput = True

    #set the workspace
    arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\Windows\Documents\JO_GIS_Analyst"

    #Get a list of rasters and convert to shapefile
    for raster in arcpy.ListRasters("nofpt*", "TIF"):
        print raster #check the presence of rasters"
        #convert the raster to polygon
        arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(raster, raster +".shp", "SIMPLIFY")
    print "Finish converting the rasters to polygon"
```

the output of print is the name of my raster file, the first item on my list:

```
    nofptreprojected_2014121_geog.tif
```

the exact error message is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File"C:\Users\Windows\Dropbox\PythonScripts\batch_convert_raster_to_polygon.py", line 22, in <module>
      arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(raster, r"C:\Users\Windows\Documents\JO_GIS_Analyst\\" + raster + ".shp", "SIMPLIFY")
     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 178, in RasterToPolygon
      raise e
     ExecuteError: ERROR 010157: Unable to open feature class C:\Users\Windows\Documents\JO_GIS_Analyst\nofptreprojected_2014121_geog.tif.
     Failed to execute (RasterToPolygon).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it is cut off in the output you posted it appears that you are trying to create a shapefile named `nofptreprojected_2014121_geog.tif.shp` which I suspect is not a valid shapefile name.

Try replacing:

```
arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(raster, raster +".shp", "SIMPLIFY")
```

with:

```
arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(raster, raster.replace("tif","shp"), "SIMPLIFY")
```

or even simpler - purely as a test:

```
arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(raster, "test.shp", "SIMPLIFY")
```